# Shell - pass stderror to second shell script and use it

Tags: linux, shell, stderr

I would like to execute a shell script, and pass the stderr to the second script. How do I access the stderr from shell1.sh within shell2.sh and read the data to find some text in there?

```
sh shell1.sh | sh shell2.sh
```

Comment: You can't; the shell gets it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply redirect the `stderr` to `stdout` (using `2>&1`) before piping it into your other program:

```
sh shell1.sh 2>&1 | sh shell2.sh
```

Whatever enters the pipe through the `stdout`, will exit the pipe through the `stdin`, so your other program will then see both the original `stdout` and `stderr` on the `stdin`.

If you are not interested in the (original) `stdout` of the first program, just re-direct it to `/dev/null`

```
sh shell1.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | sh shell2.sh
```

Note, that there is only a single input channel for a program (`stdin`), so once you have redirected `stderr` to `stdout` there is no way to differentiate between the original `stdout` and `stderr` in your piped-to program.

Comment: Thank you - and how do I access it in the other file? should I just try echo 2? or how can I search for a certain word for example?

Comment: it will appear on the stdin

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to **pass only stderr** to RHS command while ignoring stdout:

```
sh shell1.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | shell2.sh
```

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and `>/dev/null` redirects stdout to `null`.